# passing two parameter from two selects to a controller function in Grails

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, grails

In my view i have two dropdownlists, one is populated by the other. and a button in which i need to pass the values of the both selects to use them in a query in a controller function.

Can anyone help me out with this either to enhance my search references or to figure it out.
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the limited description you've provided, I don't see why you can't use a regular Grails form with 2 selects.

```
<g:form controller="book" action="something">

  <g:select name="param1" from="${1..3}"/>
  <g:select name="param2" from="${4..6}"/>

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</g:form>
```

Comment: thnx for the help that was useful since am pretty new in grails.
am wondering how i can use the two selected values in a query in a controller function.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the $.ajax method of jquery

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'controllerName/actionName',
  data: {paramName: 'value1', paramName2 : 'value2'}
});
```